# C# application : Localization dlls missing after building installer

Tags: c#, forms, localization, installation, ilmerge

I'm working on this form application where i use localization in a C# project, where the different text entries are stored in resource files (GlobalLanguages.resx and GlobalLanguages.fr.resx). These are set to be Embedded.

Everything works great when running the application in debug/release in VS 2008, and it also works when i start the exe from the output folder outside of VS 2008. But when i build the visual studio installer project to get my installer and install it on my machine, the localization is not working. Even tho there is a .dll file in the installation folder containing the .fr.resx values.

The installer project is set up to include the localization output of the main project. And outputting the current locale of the installed app to a log files does give the correct value, but the texts are displayed in the default language.

We do use IlMerge to merge several .dll files in the exe, but since the .dll for the resource can be found, i guess that should not be the problem. I've really tried everything, but i'm out of idea's now...

Hope you guys can help.

Thanks

Comment: Is the GlobalLanguages.fr.dll file in the same folder as the exe or in a "fr" dir under the exe  dir? Does it change the behavior if you change this?

Comment: it's in a sub folder "fr" like you said. I'll try and move it to the main folder and see if it does anything as soon as I get back to my pc. Thanks

Comment: Just having the same folder structure as when in the bin/debug under VS should be correct. Also, make sure you try without ilmerge to rule that out of the equation.

Comment: Haven't been able to try it yet since i'm not at the office atm, but i can confirm that in the debug folder, the resource dll is also in a sub folder "fr", so same set-up. I'll also try it without IlMerging it, even tho the installer does place the resource dll in the installation folder. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Tried it, but it's still not working. Thanks anyway...

Is there any way to check if the localization resource can be accessed or exists?

Comment: I'll post some code you can try in order to track down the problem but I'll do it in an answer in order to get readable syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this just for diagnosis: (you need to change classnames/namespace obviously).

```
 Type t = typeof(SomeClassInLanguageAssembly);
 Assembly languageAssembly = t.Assembly;
 Console.WriteLine("Current UI culture: "+Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
 Console.WriteLine("Resources in assembly:");
 languageAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
 ResourceManager r = new ResourceManager("Language.Assembly.Namespace.ResourceName", languageAssembly);
 Console.WriteLine("'YES' -> " + r.GetString("YES"));
```

If i run that it outputs for example:

Current UI culture: fr

Resources in assembly:

Company.Application.Language.Resources.resources

'YES' -> Oui

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, i'll try it out later. For now, i've just split up the languages in two separate resource files and wrote my own controller to retrieve the correct value. Been wasting too much time finding a solution and i got a proof of concept deadline for the application in about two hours. Thank you so much for your assistance.